# UITableView didSelectRowAtIndex wrong index mapping

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I am encountering a situation where in some edge case the **indexpath is mapped wrongly**.

One more observation the **scrolling also gets screwed** in same scenario.

Occurence is very low like 0.1% but experience is very bad when this happens.

What are the patterns which can cause this?

Comment: Can you please share code of didSelectRowAtIndex ? It will be helpful to find issue.

Comment: Please share the code of tableview delegate methods

Comment: sharing code is difficult as it contains lots of business logic. Can reloading data and insertion/deletion happening at same time cause this?

Comment: @RohitGarg Yes, it's possible. I thing I had similar issues a while ago.

Comment: Show code. Surely something you did wrong.

Comment: Make sure that you are using "didSelectRowAtIndexPath" and not "didDeselectRowAtIndexPath". It could be the issue you are not getting proper indexPath

Comment: @Pushkraj- I am sure i am using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` as it is working fine in 99.9% cases. Will try to debug it on weekend. If i am unable to find the cause will share the code. Thanks anyways!!